# N-iterations of a string

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I have a string `s`. I take all even-indexed characters of the string `s` and push them to the front, while all the odd-indexed characters go to the back. Then, I concatenate the `s` string.

Now, I want to do this `N-times`, however the code I'm using fails miserably for long strings and `N` greater than a billion.

```
def n_iters(s, n):
    for i in range(n):
        s = s[::2] + s[1::2]
    return s
```

Any idea how to optimize this?

A sample that the code fails for would be a string `s` of length `8000000` and `N = 100000000`.

Comment: What sign of failure do you observe? It works for me for a 8M `str` with `N == 10`.

Comment: @norok2 I have a time constraint of 12000 ms to execute this and with the code above it simply times out.

Comment: An option could be to rewrite it in a single string concatenaton avoiding the for loop. It should be possible... e.g. `def n_iters(s, n): return ''.join(s[a:b:c] for i in range)`. The tricky part is to find `a`, `b` and `c`. It looks possible, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @baduker, post a representative test string which fails and `n` value, so we not run into guessing

Comment: FWIW, this `def n_iters2(s, n): return ''.join(s[(i * 2 ** n) % len(s)] for i in range(len(s)))` is equivalent to `def n_iters(s, n): for i in range(n): s = s[::2] + s[::2]; return s` so pretty close to what you are looking for, but it is way slower. Not sure this can be made significantly faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this can be sped up with the following approach.

```
def n_inters(s, n):
    iterations = [s]
    while True:
       s = s[::2] + s[1::2]
       if s == iterations[0]: break
       iterations.append(s)

    return iterations[n % len(iterations)]
```